# Can't store previous state in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to make a 2048 like game in react native. I wanted to check if the state of the game is equal to the previous state, but the previous state is always overwritten. I'm not an expert in react, so it's probably an obvious bug that I couldn't notice but after several hours of debugging I couldn't get it working.

```
let newState = this.state.gameState;
let previous = this.state.gameState;
console.log(previous) // shows the previous state
// calculate newState
console.log(previous) // the variable previous has changed and is in sync with newState
this.setState({ gameState: newState });
```

There are probably other ways to implement this but this is the easiest and I would have to rewrite a lot of code to make it work without this state checking.

Comment: can you post the rough shape of your state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are multiple places that update the state, the above approach could result in out-of-sync values. The best solution is using [`setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) with an updater function:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  const { gameState: prevGameState } = prevState;
  const newGameState = {
    ...prevGameState,
    positionX: prevGameState.positionX + 1,
    // ...
  };
  return { ...prevState, gameState: newGameState };
});
```

Of course, if your previous `gameState` includes arrays, objects, etc, your updater will need more code, but the idea is the same: use updater function if you need to use the current state values to generate new state values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. In my updater function I created a new game state from the previous and before returning it I compared it to the old state but the two arrays are the same.

Comment: I did something like this:
`this.setState(prevState => {
  let { gameState: newState } = prevState;
  // do something to newState array
  compareArrays(newState, prevState.gameState); // they have the exact same value
  return { gameState: newState };
})`

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? Destructuring so that you're not mutating the current state value?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work, at least with the way I structured my data. I guess calling .slice() on a 2d array wasn't enough and modifying the copied variable changed the original state, so I wrote a simple function to copy the 2d array and it works now. Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: You could also use `deepClone` of lodash.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid updating state directly because re-rendering won't happen if you mutate state directly.

> **NEVER** mutate this.state directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if
>   it were immutable.

`setState()` does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains. `setState()` will always trigger a re-render unless conditional rendering logic is implemented in `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

If mutable objects are being used and the logic cannot be implemented in `shouldComponentUpdate()`, calling `setState()` only when the new state differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

Example-

```
this.setState(prev=>({
   gameState: prev.gameState + 1 
}))
```

for reference check official docs [Using State Correctly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)